# regular dll vs extension dll

Tags: windows, dll, mfc

I have a DLL (A.dll) that uses ATL stuff, and can't have MFC in it. There is some stuff it needs that is MFC though, so I made a [MFC regular DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), called B.dll and it gets automatically loaded at runtime by A.dll (via an import library).

The part of B.dll that A needs is a class (foo) defined in B.dll, and the class has some stuff in it that uses MFC. Am i allowed to create a foo object in A.dll? Does B need to be an extension DLL instead?

The Regular DLL page says:

> All memory allocations within a
>   regular DLL should stay within the
>   DLL; the DLL should not pass to or
>   receive from the calling executable
>   any of the following:
>
> - Pointers to MFC objects
> - Pointers to memory allocated by MFC

but the extension DLL page says

> The client executable must be an MFC application compiled with _AFXDLL defined., and A.dll can't be an MFC app.

Is it a problem to use a regular DLL in this case?

Thanks,

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if A can't use MFC, and B provides a class that does, how can you instantiate an object in A? Are you looking to have B have a factory function that creates the object and passes it to A through a pointer? In that case you need to ensure that B calls delete() on it, not A, because they'll have two different heaps.

Is this a COM object or what do you mean by 'import library'? Are we talking the 'regular' dll way with the stubs in the .lib, or an 'import library' .tlb? (Not that it matters for the question I think, I'm just trying to picture the situation).

Comment: I originally had A creating an MFC object defined in B. I think that's what was causing my heap errors. I now changed it to a function where the object's lifetime is managed by B and A  accesses is through exported functions.

It's not a com object. The import library is a .lib file generated by the compiler or linker or whatever when you specify something as __declspec(dllexport) or in a def file. And then anything that imports that and links against the import library will automatically load the dll at runtime.

Comment: OK that's clear. Yes mixing new/delete across dll boundaries gives unexpected results sometimes. It's exacerbated by the possibility that a dll will share the heap with other dll's at one moment, and then when an update to the CRT is installed it starts using its own heap (depending on the manifest settings). I think the common wisdom is to never have modules free memory that was allocated by another module, in other words like you say have each module do its own memory management. If I remember correctly, dlls with _USRDLL/_AFXDLL have a different heap all together, to do MFC-specific things.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that a regular DLL is the right choice.

The main concern with regular DLL is that if it were loaded into an MFC app, there would be two independent copies of MFC and all metadata.  The advice you found is written to make sure that metadata lookups don't go to the wrong copy.  Not a problem in your scenario.